# synchronising tabpages and their controls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, tabs

I have x number of TabPages, on each of the TabPages is an AddressBar control and a WebBrowser Control. The WebBrowser control (custom control) has a property of type int called BrowserCount.

The BrowserCount value should be the same as the TabPage upon which it is located. So TabPage[0] has a Browser with BrowserCount = 0; etc

However, when I delete a TabPage the numbers go out of synch. Clearly the answer is to simply iterate through the remaining TabePages and reset the BrowserCount to the TabPages new index.

I have this code:

```
private void UpdateTabs()
    {
        // Renumber Tabs and Browsers
        int tabCount = 0;
        foreach (TabPage tp in customTabControl1.TabPages)
        {
            tp.Tag = tabCount;
            foreach (Control ctrl in tp.Controls)
            {
                if (ctrl.Name == "browser")
                {
                    ctrl.BrowserCount = TabCount; // Error Unknown member BrowserCount
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It would appear I need to get hold of the actual instance of the Browser on that tab to access the BrowserCount property (Which isn't a property at all, it's just a public (non-static) variable).

Any ideas how I can get the Browser's BrowseCount to be renumbered so that they are the same as the parent TabPage's Index?

Thanks.

Comment: You could use the TabControl Count property as the source of your iterator.

Comment: How 'bout implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your `TabPage` and raise event when the index changed? You need to create your own `TabPage` with this approach thought

Comment: One thing you can do is you can raise an event which is handled by your customTabControl. This way you do not have to hold the actual instance of the Browser on a particular tab page.

Comment: I know when the tab and browser's are closing - I just need to resynch the browser number to the tab index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> // Error Unknown member BrowserCount

Right...because your variable "ctrl" is of type Control, and Control has no such property/field called "BrowserCount".

You need to CAST "ctrl" to the correct type.  This could look something like:

```
        int tabCount = 0;
        foreach (TabPage tp in customTabControl1.TabPages)
        {
            tp.Tag = tabCount;
            foreach (Control ctrl in tp.Controls)
            {
                if (ctl is YourUserControlTypeHere)
                {
                    YourUserControlTypeHere uc = (YourUserControlTypeHere)ctl;
                    uc.BrowserCount = TabCount; // Error Unknown member BrowserCount
                }
            }
        }
```